# how to convert german charater in to utf string in pdf parsing in iphone?

Tags: iphone

I have implementing pdf parsing in which i have parsed pdf and fetch the all text but it disply junks characters so i want to convert in to utf string.How it possible please help me for this question.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to find out which encoding is currently used for the text. I guess it's ISO-8859-1, aka Latin-1 or it's variant ISO-8859-15, aka Latin-15.

As soon as know that it's a piece of cake. You haven't said in which container you got the text, e.g. whether it's stored in a C string or NSData.

Let's assume you got a C string. In that case you would do:

```
myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:myCString
                                    length:strlen(myCString)
                                  encoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];
```

If you got a NSData, you would use the `initWithData:encoding:` initializer instead. That's all you need to do, as according to Apple's documentation, "*A string object presents itself as an array of Unicode characters*". If you need a UTF8-encoded C string, you can then query it via:

```
myUTF8CString = [myString UTF8String];
```

There's also `dataUsingEncoding:` to get a NSData object instead of a C string.

Have a look at the [NSString class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) and the [NSStringEncoding constants](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-BAJJAICE).